# Obter retorno JSON de uma URL dentro da função

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho a seguinte função:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
arrayAmount[0]='29.90';
}
```

Eu preciso, em vez de especificar o valor diretamente ali (29.90), que ele obtenha o valor de uma URL.

Ex:

```
arrayAmount[0]=GET:http://domain_here.com?id=1;
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Preciso de algo que seja em apenas um comando/linha, pois serão vários `array`..

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro defina no seu javascript:

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return results[1] || 0;
}
```

Depois use:

```
var parametro1 = $.urlParam('nome_do_parametro_na_url');
```

```js
$.urlParam = function(name){
  var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec("http://dominio.com?id=3&city=SP");
  return results[1] || 0;
}

var person = new Object();
person.id = $.urlParam("id");
person.city = $.urlParam("city");
console.log(person);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  Substitua <b>http://dominio.com?id=3&city=SP</b> no código acima<br>
  Por <b>window.location.href</b> para pegar a url atual
```

Comment: Na verdade o que eu preciso é que ele pegue o valor que a URL retorna em JSON, ou seja, o valor é retornado somente quando a URL é acessada. O `id=1` é uma referência do plano, para plano possuí um valor diferente.

Comment: Se o JSON estiver sendo passado na url pelo GET, é só fazer o mesmo, mas usando a função do JS pra converter em JSON ``var obj = JSON.parse($.urlParam("json");``

Comment: Na verdade não é em JSON, é apenas em texto simples. Quando acesso a URL é exibido na tela apenas um valor, por exemplo: 79.90

Comment: Nesse caso sua dica vai funcionar também?